# Replace two words that may have one or more of any kind of whitespace between them

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace

I'm a newcomer to regular expressions, and am having a hard time with what appears to be a simple case.

I need to replace "foo bar" with "fubar", where there is any amount and variety of white space between foo and bar.

For what it's worth, I'm using php's eregi_replace() to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`... =` [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace)`('/foo\s+bar/', 'fubar', ...);`

Comment: Oh, and if you want to replace 'foobar' too, you have to use \s* instead of \s+. "*" means "zero or more times" (the "*" symbol came directly from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), and "+" means "one or more time". "\s" stands for "any whitespace character". Plain unescaped alphanumerics have no special meaning.

Comment: It is a good idea to use preg_* (like drdaeman has used) instead of ereg_*. The former uses perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE), which are the de facto standard now and far-better documented on the webs.

Comment: This expression performs exactly as I'd hoped. Thanks drdaeman, and others, for the help, and for the helpful extra comments.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice you've said ereg*i*. If you need to make regexp case insensitive use "i" flag in regexp: preg_replace('/foo\s+bar/i', ...)

Comment: wouldn't the pattern be better if it looked more like this?

    ... = preg_replace( '/(\w+)\s+(\w+)/', '\\1\\2', ...);

Comment: Well, I understood it that he needs to replace "foo bar" with "fubar" (not "foobar", which your code would do). So, that's exactly what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the `eregi_replace` syntax, but you'd want something like this:

```
Pattern: foo\s*bar
Replace with: fubar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find = '(foo)\s*(bar)'
replace = '\\1\\2'
```

\s is the metachar for any whitespace character.

Comment: Good example on using capturing brackens, but Lasoldo Solsifa wants to replace "foo bar" with "fubar", not "foobar".

Answer (score 0):

I also prefer [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), but for completeness, here it is with [`ereg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php):

```
$pattern     = "foo[[:space:]]+bar";
$replacement = "fubar";
$string = "foo    bar";
print ereg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

that prints "fubar"

Comment: Actually, $pattern = "foo[[:space:]]+bar"; $replacement = "fubar";. Otherwise it will happily replace "foo baz" too, which is probably not something we want.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that you are making whole word matches on `foo` and `bar`, it is critical to add word boundaries.  `\s+` will match one or more whitespaces.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GMZBC))

```
$strings = [
    'foo barf',
    "foo bar",
    "kungfoo bar"
];

var_export(preg_replace('/\bfoo\s+bar\b/', 'fubar', $strings));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'foo barf',
  1 => 'fubar',
  2 => 'kungfoo bar',
)
```