# replace . from email address

Tags: php, regex, email, preg-replace

I have a text string. That may or maynot contain email addresses. I want to replace all . (fullstop) to dot.

```
blah blah abcd@gmail.com  fooo some content and email again
```

to

```
blah blah abcd@gmail dot com  fooo some content and email again
```

Can I do this using regex?

-Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 3):

If you had the .NET regex engine at your disposal, you could do it in a single regex by searching for `(?:.(?=\S+@)|(?<=@\S+).)` and replacing all matches with `dot`.

In PHP, you'd have to do it in two steps/iteratively:

Search for `\.(?=\S+@)` and replace with `dot`:

```
$subject = preg_replace('/\.(?=\S+@)/', ' dot ', $subject);
```

This will replace all dots in email addresses that occur before the `@`. Then search for `(@\S+)\.` and replace with `\1 dot`; repeat this until there are no further matches.

Something like

```
while (preg_match('/(@\S+)\./', $subject)) {
    $subject = preg_replace('/(@\S+)\./', '\1 dot ', $subject);
}
```

This will match a dot inside an email address after the `@`, but since PHP's regex engine doesn't support infinite lookbehind, I need to reapply the regex to the string as many times as the maximum number of dots after the `@`. For example, in the string `@foo.bar.com`, it will first match `@foo.bar.` and replace with `@foo.bar dot`. Then, in the next run, it replaces `@foo.` with `@foo dot`.

Answer (score 0):

Step one [Regex Get Email handle from Email Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621660/regex-get-email-handle-from-email-address) and / or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261/test-expand-my-email-regex

Step two [regex to replace "foo-some white space-bar" with "fubar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982544/regex-to-replace-foo-some-white-space-bar-with-fubar)

Taking the teach a man to fish approach.